# ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead

Tags: seaborn, histogram, visualization, kernel-density

I am trying to plot a histogram using seaborn. When I try to set kde=True this error is returned:
ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.

```
sns.histplot(data=df, x='age', kde=True);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11):

I believe that you have an incompatibility between your version of matplotlib and your version of pandas, with seaborn caught in the middle (source: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3312)

Answer (score 11):

This can also happen in Matplotlib.  I have a virtual environment with matplotlib=3.3.0 and pandas=2.0.2.

A workaround is to use the dataframe's values attribute which will return a numpy array, which can then be used in the plotting function:

```
plt.plot(df['var_name'].values, df['other_var_name'].values)
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) states: _Warning: We recommend using `DataFrame.to_numpy()` instead._

Comment: Upvoted. I [added an answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77093952/4561887), with more detail and the recommendation to use `.to_numpy()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you must convert the object to a NumPy array via [`pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) for plotting with `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`.

For this error:

> `` ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead. ``

Full context:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/gabriel/my/file.py", line 120, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/home/gabriel/my/file.py", line 98, in main
>     plt.plot(
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2757, in plot
>     return gca().plot(
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1632, in plot
>     lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 312, in __call__
>     yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 487, in _plot_args
>     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 1327, in _check_1d
>     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
>   File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1072, in __getitem__
>     return self._get_with(key)
>   File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1082, in _get_with
>     return self._get_values_tuple(key)
>   File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1122, in _get_values_tuple
>     disallow_ndim_indexing(result)
>   File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers/utils.py", line 341, in disallow_ndim_indexing
>     raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
> ```

[`.values` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76533428/4561887):

```py
plt.plot(df['var_name'].values, df['other_var_name'].values)
```

...but [the `pandas.DataFrame.values` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) states:

> Warning: We recommend using `DataFrame.to_numpy()` instead.

**So, [`.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) is recommended instead:**

```py
plt.plot(df['var_name'].to_numpy(), df['other_var_name'].to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

You may upgrade your packages, but it may not be compatible with other libraries such as TensorFlow, so, you may have to downgrade the package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This code below:

plt.plot(df['var_name'].to_numpy(), df['other_var_name'].to_numpy())

IT WORKED PERFECTLY for ME as WELL!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

step 1. check np.ndim(your_df) for your_df. If output print(np.ndim(your_df)): 1, then go to step 2

step 2.
find and change utils.py via nano, you need set "if np.ndim(result) > 2":

def disallow_ndim_indexing(result) -> None:
"""
Helper function to disallow multi-dimensional indexing on 1D Series/Index.

```
GH#27125 indexer like idx[:, None] expands dim, but we cannot do that
and keep an index, so we used to return ndarray, which was deprecated
in GH#30588.
    nnv_comment: default np.ndim(result) > 1
"""     
if np.ndim(result) > 2:
    raise ValueError(
        "Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer "
        "supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead."
    )
```

step 3. reboot and try again